# Angular js ngRoute is not working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

Hi I'm learning angular js. I'm using angular 1.5.6 version. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="NoteWrangler">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='/NoteWrangler/javascript/vendor/angular.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='/NoteWrangler/javascript/vendor/angular-route.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='/NoteWrangler/javascript/route.js'></script>

        <a href="#/genere">Genere</a>
        <a href="#/instruments">Instruments</a>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My javascript file

```
angular.module('NoteWrangler',['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/genere',{
        templateUrl: '/template/genere/index.html'
    })
    .when('/instruments',{
        templateUrl: '/template/instruments/index.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/template/genere/index.html'
    });
}]);
```

I'm doing same as they teach in a tutorial, but I'm not able to re route to templateUrl. What i'm doing wrong here? I didn't find any errors in console. I search in every tutorial they do the same. I don't know what i'm doing wrong here. Can some one help me to solve this please?

Comment: maybe it's dependency had conflict.  see [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/QAZVEznRAJvU7YmkoDEu?p=preview)

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by dependency?Do you mean my javascript file?

Comment: I mean the `ngRoute`  that you injected into your app.

Comment: ok ok I'll try in your way thank you.

Comment: @e.k remove the slash after the hash tag on the href value. <a href="#genere">Genere</a><a href="#instruments">Instruments</a>

Comment: Also you should redirect to `url` not `templateUrl` in `otherwise` such as `/genere`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove first slash in your templateUrl eg: /template/genere/index.html to template/genere/index.html

Comment: yes thank you! it is working! but in any tutorials they added '/' before path